# Gradle - How to add some delay pause hang in Gradle

Tags: gradle, task, delay, sleep, onpause

Im looking for a way to insert a pause of few seconds between the calls of two gradle tasks.

I can use

```
firstTask.doLast {

.....

}
```

something like which can do Linux/Unix

```
sleep 45
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, I'd try to find a better solution than waiting for so long every time. Anyway, to delay the first task for 45 seconds, you can do:

```
firstTask.doLast {
    sleep(45 * 1000)
}
```

A good way to familiarize yourself with Groovy's core APIs is to study the [Groovy JDK](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/) (also known as GDK). It's also a handy reference.

Comment: Or:
    `firstTask {
      // some stuff here;
      doLast { 
        sleep(45 * 1000)
      }
    }`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run integration tests in Tomcat, then simply use the [Gradle Tomcat Plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) like this:

```
ext {
    tomcatStopPort = 8081
    tomcatStopKey = 'stopKey'
}

task integrationTomcatRun(type: org.gradle.api.plugins.tomcat.TomcatRun) {
    stopPort = tomcatStopPort
    stopKey = tomcatStopKey
    daemon = true
}

task integrationTomcatStop(type: org.gradle.api.plugins.tomcat.TomcatStop) {
    stopPort = tomcatStopPort
    stopKey = tomcatStopKey
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    include '**/*IntegrationTest.*'
    dependsOn integrationTomcatRun
    finalizedBy integrationTomcatStop
}

test {
    exclude '**/*IntegrationTest.*'
}
```

Comment: Hi Vidya, Can you provide a way to add a delay. firstTask deploys a .war in Tomcat (which is already running, so basically tomcat just takes 30-45 seconds to recycle to pick the new .war provided by the new build), i want to wait 45 seconds after that happens and before I call gradle integrationTest task (i.e. my secondTask).

Comment: Actually the one you mentioned I had that code already but all I needed was how to insert delay. Due to lot of customizations we have, I think we can't use Gradle's Tomcat Plugin but thanks for your inputs. Thanks Vidya.